# I need your ideas on creating a new dynamic website

Tags: php

I am thinking of building a new page but I don't want to based on cms like Joomla, Wordpress and so on.
I have a quite good knowledge of PHP, but I can't do something 100% without any help.

My question is are there any softwares or frameworks that let you build something with their functions ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Web_application_frameworks#PHP_2

Comment: You don't have enough information in your question for us to give you an answer.  What exactly are you trying to do, what is your problem, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to setup and configure a web server so that you can run php on some files inside php-enabled directories.

search google for "LAMP tutorial".

Do you prefer to work on a Microsoft platform ? If so, then google for "WAMP tutorial".